# Run pipline on slave not master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running [Jenkins pipline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) (on Jenkins v2.58) and am trying to get the build to run on a slave not the master. Yet, whatever magic I try in the Jenkinsfile, Jenkins keeps running on master.

*How do I specify a slave executor?*

Here is my toy Jenkinsfile, if that helps:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label='CentOS7'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Creating tox virtual environment') {
            steps { 
                sh 'uname -a'
                sh 'tox -v --recreate' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right syntax appears to be:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'CentOS7' }

    stages {
        stage('Creating tox virtual environment') {
            steps { 
                sh 'uname -a'
                sh 'tox -v --recreate' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure your master is running.

Comment: feel free to accept your answer (if and when you are able to) so others know it is sorted out. thanks!

Comment: Since you made quite an obvius syntax error, I would even propose removing this question altogether.  Unless you believe that someone else is going to write the exact same wrong code you came up with...

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo The pipeline documentation is pretty poor but whatever. I do not care that much either way…