# How do I make Jenkins pipeline run in (any) agent machine, but never master?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My  Jenkins pipeline  randomly alternates between running on master and on agent (slave) machines.

The whole pipeline  has only one `agent` statement, thus:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
}
```

How can I get the build to run in load-balanced agents, and never master?

- Maybe it could be done with `agent { label 'some-label' }`. Is there a predefined label that specifies   agents  and not master? Or do I have to label all agents myself?
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733917/) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/922352/) show how to choose   a *specific* agent, but I want random balancing between agent machines.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267523/) discusses `agent any` vs `agent none`, but neither of those blocks the master from being used.
- [This page](https://zwischenzugs.com/2017/04/23/things-i-wish-i-knew-before-using-jenkins-pipelines/) recommends wrapping everything in a `node` stanza, but that seems to force the build to run on master or a specified node, which again does not allow balancing of agents.

Comment: You can add labels to workers and use that in node 

`node("label") {
 //execution statement
}` here instead of label you can give node name to run in specific node.  there is label section in configure node page. labels are separated by white-space

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `node('!master') {...}` or `agent { label '!master' }` syntax. See more details [there](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node).

Also there is a solution from [Jenkins Best Practices](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Best+Practices) page for setting limitation on master node itself:

> If you have a more complex security setup that allows some users to only configure jobs, but not administer Jenkins, you need to prevent them from running builds on the master node, otherwise they have unrestricted access into the JENKINS_HOME directory. You can do this by setting the executor count to zero. Instead, make sure all jobs run on agents. This ensures that the jenkins master can scale to support many more jobs, and it also protects builds from modifying potentially sensitive data on $JENKINS_HOME accidentally/maliciously. If you need some jobs to run on the master (e.g. backups of Jenkins itself), use the [Job Restrictions Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin) to limit which jobs can be executed there.

**UPDATE**: As @Moshisho mentioned, the built-in node was renamed from "*master node*" to "*built-in node*" in Jenkins 2.307 and in Jenkins 2.319.1.
So, now it should be `agent { label '!built-in' }`. See details [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/built-in-node-migration/).

Comment: From Jenkins 2.307 and Jenkins 2.319.1 it should be `agent { label '!built-in' }`.

Answer (score 2):

When configuring node restrictions based on labels for freestyle jobs in the jenkins web interface, you can do this with the expression `!master`. The boolean operators `||` and `&&` are also supported.

I'm not sure whether the pipeline configuration supports the same expression syntax, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: how can i do it in pipelines? Tried `agent { label "include" && "!exclude" }` and `agent { label "include && !exclude"}` and it could run on "exclude" node.

Comment: The second approach should work according to https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node

Comment: Thank you, on the second glance it really seems to work.